# How to add preview link for each post in blogger homepage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, blogger

I am creating a blogger template resource and the template I use has a preview button for each post in the homepage. I want to put the link there for each post that the viewer could directly to the preview of that template.

My website link: [themes.tipricks.com](https://themes.tipricks.com)

You can check on the site I mentioned below this site have preview buttons for each post. I want to show links like this.

[Example Site](https://www.blantertheme.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add HTML preview buttons in each post before the jumplink.

For example,
You can add a link to the preview site:

```
<a target="_blank" href="to-your-preview"> Live Preview</a>
```

just before `<!--more-->`

and in the template of your blog, you can choose to show excerpt before the jumplink (which now contains your live preview button) and use the jumplink button to show more details of the template or avoid it altogether.